# When calling transfer from an ERC20 with ethers, the transaction passes and is mined, but the token doesn't show

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, ethers.js

I am new to all this and would be thankful if anyone could direct me to a place I can read a bit more in depth about this and give me an explanation why this doesn't work and why the solutions work. Thanks a lot.

```
const USDT2 = new ethers.Contract(contract address, abi,wallet);//The wallet itself works fine
async function geterc20(){
    const options = {
        gasLimit: 150000,
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('10.0', 'gwei')
    };
    
   await USDT2.transfer(ACCOUNT2_PUBLIC_KEY,ethers.BigNumber.from(100),options).then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(ethers.utils.toUtf8String(Object.values(error.body)));
    });
 
    
}
```

Comment: I’m sorry but your answers and comments are sometime a bit aggressive… please try to be more patient with new developers @Nulik

Comment: @alex234 not understanding you, I gave this guy a tip on how to get lots of high quality information and you are complaining. Think positive!

Comment: @Nulik I agree with MajdTL on this case, telling someone to use google isn't a good advice, instead provide an article or tutorial.

Comment: Are you testing with a public testnet? Do you have the failed transfer transaction hash? Can you retrieve the transaction receipt? There are several things that coul be wrong, wrong sender or recipient, not enough balance, wrong token address, wrong abi.

Comment: @Ismael , the OP asked for places where he could read more, if you din't notice

Comment: Sorry,  for the late replies, I did some trouble shooting a bit later and it turns out the contract instance wasn't being deployed, with an error:contract not deployed. With a catch function, I got reason: 'contract not deployed',
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  contractAddress: '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7',
  operation: 'getDeployed'                                                                                                          Does this mean that this function doesn't exist? I'm using the latest version of ethers however?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transfer `ethers.BigNumber.from(100)` value on USDT contract, which use a decimal value of 6, you are actually transferring 0.0001 USDT.

You should use `ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 6)` to generate a proper value that represents 100 USDT.

Now even though technically you sent 0.0001 USDT, but depending on the user interface you are using to view the balance, it might be rounding to 2 fractional digits.

If you want to verify that you can use `USDT2.balanceOf(ACCOUNT2_PUBLIC_KEY)` to view the exact balance.

Comment: I see, thanks @Soham_Zemse. One thing I'm curious though, isn't big number an 18 digit number? How can a 6 digit number be larger than that ? Is it something related to uint256? Also, the transaction showed, but no values were changed, here is the transaction hash: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x44ea402c2522b6d9302c833f435bd3a0cf34d789a006578ed38675c83a326359. As mentioned in my other 2 comments, the contract instance deployment itself seemed to have issues. I can call all properties but none of the functions.

Comment: @Ismael♦,  so I don't think I was clear enough particularly as I am using a public testnet, Rinkeby to be exact and it looks as if the contract instance is not being deployed. Oddly enough, I deployed another contract instance using the same wallet with a different abi, and that works just fine. The abi I however is a standard ERC20 abi and for good measure, I copied the mainnet USDT Abi.  As stated above, it looks as if the instance isn't intializing but transactions still show up. The rinkeby etherscan transaction in the previous comment to @SohamZemse is one of them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tx hash, the USDT contract address (0xdac..) that you're using is of mainnet, while this address does not have any bytecode on Rinkeby. That's why the tx you sent didn't execute any EVM code, and you were only charged with intrinsic. So you just have to use an address that is a ERC20 contract on rinkeby.

Comment: And BigNumber, despite of it's misleading name, is just a number (actually an integer), and only appealing property it has that doesn't have an upper bound, in comparison to the usual JS Number in which you can have upto 2^53-1 without losing precision, that's why we have to use BigNumber. But that we have to scale it up depending on the decimals we are working with.